# Need event when specific program is launched in order to attach process

Tags: windows, events, task, scheduled-tasks

I have a specific program that I want to run a script when its launched.

I have looked into batch scripts and what not but the problem is the associated program might not be launched through that specific batch script but opened through a saved project.

I would like to create an event whenever this specific program starts up that i can use to attach a script start when it does.

The issue is that when I start the program I can't find any corresponding event.

Perhaps I'm not looking for the correct thing.

Comment: What other research have you done? To assist answerers you should be as specific as possible about the problem description and demonstration of research effort/solve attempts ([How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). For example, have you checked out this post? https://superuser.com/questions/603226/does-windows-log-programs-that-have-been-run-called

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screnshot]

If there is an event logged on startup of your application you can use the windows task scheduler -> Action - > Create Task -> Trigger and select Begin the task on event and find the event logged on startup.

Comment: this has been to current approach but unfortunately the application does not log an event

Comment: Run secpol.msc and navigate to Advanced Audit... => System Audit... => Detailed Tracking. Enable "Audit Process Creation" for "Success". This will add a Process Creation event (ID 4688) to the Security log whenever a new process is created. Add a custom trigger with this manual XML query: `<QueryList><Query Id="0" Path="Security"><Select Path="Security">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and EventID=4688] and EventData[Data[@Name='NewProcessName']='C:\Path\To\Application.exe']]</Select></Query></QueryList>`. Modify this with the actual path of the executable.